# Reason for Subversion merge variations

Tags: git, svn, merge

Though I typically use git I am, at least at work, forced to use Subversion.  I understand that many, if not all, of the differences between the two boil down to git being distributed and Subversion being centralized, but merging in Subversion seems to have an additional layer of complexity that seems separate.  In particular the `--reintegrate` option seems a bit unnecessary to me.

Is there a particular design decision that led to Subversion having different types of merges or maybe a less obvious consequence of a centralized system?  Or am I just not seeing some connection between the options for merging in git and the forms of merges available in Subversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably google some [good resources](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion-merg) on this topic, but I would add two cents:

1. Subversion originally didn't track which revision was merged to which branch. It had a model of branches as tree branches - no cycles, no tracking of the fact that you reintegrated the same change to two different branches. You were doing the merges by selecting needed commits manually. More advanced merging techniques were added on top of this model which naturally led to certain clumsiness.
2. Technically, this question about merging has no relation to the distributed v centralized model and you would get the same differences with single isolated git repository v svn.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about SVN, but to the best of my knowledge, SVN stores diffs between versions, while Git stores actual snapshots (optimized of course). I think this aspect might have more of an impact than the fact that Git is distributed. If anything, the reason Git can afford to be distributed is because of its data model.